# Cast to union and weird number format

Tags: c++, c

Can anybody tell me how to make this C code work in C++ please?

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int( double value )
{
    return (union {double f; uint64_t i;}){value}.i;    
}
```

I'm not precisely sure what is going on, is it bit shift?

Comment: If you don't know what the code does, why do you want to use it?

Comment: Instead of c-style cast, just use `static_cast<>`.

Comment: I believe this code would cause undefined behavior in C and C++ both.

Comment: Not a bit shift. Apparently they're storing a 64 bit int in a double variable, for whatever reason, and this is the way to retrieve the original value. Why anybody would do that, no idea. I can't think of any advantages.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just as a wild guess, the OP inherited this code and now tries to understand what it does.

Comment: It is taken from library, which creates flv envelope around x264 video stream. And I guess, that flv requires some special double presentation, eg. fixed or something simillar. But Im not able to investigate it from this source. It could be little ticky..

Comment: And its possible to be compiled in C (I think C99)

Comment: @JanNovák: why don't you link against the C object files? That is, is there a reason why the code has to be ported to C++?

Comment: @Lundin: In C99, the behaviour is defined, but the value of `i` is unspecified. In C++, the behaviour is undefined (due to accessing an uninitialised object).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah you are correct. It is unspecified behavior in C, C11 6.2.6.1/7.

Comment: @Lundin n1570, 6.5.2.3 (3), fn. 95 says "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (...). This might be a trap representation." I don't think 6.2.6.1 (7) applies here because both members have (almost certainly) the same number of bits. If it's gone unchanged into the standard, it seems to be defined, but the value you get is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Lundin: the behaviour is *not* unspecified in C as long as the accessed member is of smaller or equal size than the one last stored into; there's a known defect with the annex of C99, which lists the value of union members other than the one last stored into as unspecified, whereas only the values of bytes of the object representation not used in the last store have unspecified value; this has been fixed with C11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only legal strategy for type punning in C++ is through `memcpy()`, ie

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int(double fvalue)
{
    uint64_t ivalue;
    memcpy(&ivalue, &fvalue, sizeof ivalue);
    return ivalue;
}
```

The straight-forward solution using `reinterpret_cast`

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int(double value)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(value);
}
```

is actually undefined behaviour, same as using C-style pointer casts.

Using unions (as the original solution does), while legal in C, is *probably* illegal in C++. In practice, all of these solutions are likely to work, and at least gcc-4.5.3 and clang-3.0 will produce identical code on x86 at `-O1`.

Comment: *probably* illegal in C++ is a bit vague, isn't it? I can't imagine that C++ is as restrictive with `union` of POD. There is no constructor involved here. On the other hand your solution *is* illegal, even in C++, because the alignment requirements for `double` and `uint64_t` might be different.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The `memcpy` method is legal, as long as the sizes match. Alignment isn't an issue, because both variables have the correct alignment, and `memcpy` deals with bytes and doesn't care about alignment.

Comment: @Mike, ah sorry I wasn't clear enough, I was referring to the `reinterpret_cast` which has alignment problems.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The answer correctly states that `reinterpret_cast` gives undefined behaviour, and that `memcpy` is (probably) the only legal method.

Comment: @JensGustedt: the *probably* refers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326170/cast-to-union-and-weird-number-format#comment11768623_9326284 - the standard isn't clear on what's necessary to switch the active member, but the things it does say strongly suggest that it's necessary to initialize the new member (by using placement new in case of complex types, but simple assignment should be sufficient in case of POD types); just reading from a different member does not switch the active member and is unspecified behaviour (more...)

Comment: to make a long story short: unions don't play well with RAII, and are somewhat second-class citizens in C++; even though it would have been possible to align the C++ standard with C99 in case of POD members, this hasn't been done (eg, it's nowhere mentioned what should happen in case of members of different sizes, which would be a necessity if you allow switching active members without re-initilialization); the longer I think about it, the more I'm convinced that type punning through unions is indeed illegal in C++...

Answer (score 3):

This uses a compound literal to interpret a `double` value as `uint64_t`. This construct is not available in C++. Just create a temporary variable of the union type before the return statement and use the `i` field of that variable for the return.

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int( double value )
{
    union {double f; uint64_t i;} tmp = { value };
    return tmp.i;    
}
```

**Edit:** If this is "illegal" in C++ as some claim in the comments, your best bet is probably to declare this as `extern "C"` and to compile it as C (and not C++) in a separate compilation unit. You also should be aware that this is an evil hack in any case, `double` are not guaranteed to be 64 bit wide. If you (or the code that you inherited) are just interested in the individual parts of a floating point value, use the appropriate function, `frexp`.

Comment: this is definitely legal in C, but I'm not so sure about C++: a C++ union may only have one active member, and the standard says that in *general*, you need explicit destruction and placement new to activate a different member; however, it's not so clear if that's necessary in the *specific* case of POD members, but my guess would be that type punning through union is indeed illegal in C++ as the standard doesn't specify the necessary semantics...

Comment: @christoph Its becouse I would like to use piece of c code in my c++ project. All the rest worked fine, but this.

Comment: This gives undefined behaviour in C++, since `i` is uninitialised when you access it.

Comment: @Mike, I am certainly no expert in the details of these aspects for C++. But if this is "unitialized" as you claim, meaning that `i` could contain any arbitrary value, a question about the use of `union` in C++ as a whole comes to mind. But even then the behavior wouldn't be undefined, because of the properties of `uint64_t`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It is undefined because the standard states that using an uninitialised value gives undefined behaviour. You may be able to guess what the behaviour might be in a particular situation, but that doesn't make it defined. The standard also makes it quite clear that only one member of a union is available at a time; the purpose of a union is to allow objects with non-overlapping lifetimes to share memory, not to perform otherwise disallowed type conversions.

Comment: @Mike, just to clarify, the standard you are speaking of is C++, isn't it? And you are sure that uninitialized value in C++ unconditionally gives undefined behavior? In C using unitialized values (but this wouldn't apply, here) just gives unspecific values. It would only be undefined in presence of a trap representation for the type, which is impossible here.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, I'm talking about C++, in which 4.1/1 says "If the object to which the glvalue refers is not
an object of type T and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program
that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior." In C, as you say, reading the "wrong" union member gives defined behaviour, and an unspecified value.

Comment: @Mike, no, in C the value is not unspecific if `double` has 64 bit, which seems to be tacitly assumed everywhere, here. It is the bit pattern of `f` interpreted as `uint64_t`, or more exactly of the "lowest" 64 bit of `f`, in case `double` is wider than 64 bit.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I agree, in C the value is unspecified unless you make a tacit assumption about the format of `double`. Maybe you were making that assumption; I wasn't. But this is getting wildly off-topic - let's just agree that, in C++, this code has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This C99 code is initializing an anonymous union with a `double` value, then returning the `uint64_t` value that occupies the same memory. This is a way of getting at the "bits" representing the `double`, but it's not recommended.

In fact, it's undefined behavior to read a different union member than the one that was last written.

A better way might be to just do it using pointer magic:

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int( double value )
{
  return *((uint64_t *) &value);
}
```

Comment: No, it is not undefined behavior. It is undefined behavior *if* the value that you read is a trap representation for the type through which you read. `uint64_t` by definition never has trap representations. On the other hand your version may have undefined behavior if `double` and `uint64_t` are aligned differently, but which is very unlikely.

Comment: @unwind: your answer has it backwards - type punning though unions *is* recommended whereas pointer casts invoke undefined behaviour by violating strict aliasing

Answer (score 0):

Just use pointers while casting

Remember: "types may not be defined in casts"

```
uint64_t flv_dbl2int( double value )
{
    union Foo {double f; uint64_t i;};
    return (*(Foo *)&value).i;    
}
```

Comment: Your solution is no better than unwind's. `double` and `uint64_t` might, in theory, be aligned differently, and so would `union Foo`.